# Cannot mount MTP Android device after rooting?

Tags: usb, mount, android, mtp, adb

I managed to install TWRP Recovery image `twrp-3.0.2-0-vegetahd.img` on an Aquaris E5 phone with stock Android; thereby having a rooted device.

Out of the box, the stock Android allowed USB connection and MTP mounting of the device without a problem. However, after rooting, I simply cannot get MTP mount to work again - when I plug in the device on a Ubuntu 14.04, I get:

```
Unable to mount Aquaris
No MTP devices found
```

.... and `/var/log/syslog` says:

```
kernel: [ 4319.011008] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
kernel: [ 4319.100242] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=2a47, idProduct=201d
kernel: [ 4319.100254] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
kernel: [ 4319.100261] usb 1-1.3: Product: Aquaris
kernel: [ 4319.100265] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: BQ
kernel: [ 4319.100269] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: UA0XXXXX
mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 12: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3"
mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 12 was not an MTP device
```

... and also:

```
$ adb kill-server
$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
```

Btw, this device is:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 2a47:201d
```

... and I have:

```
$ cat ~/.android/adb_usb.ini 
# ANDROID 3RD PARTY USB VENDOR ID LIST -- DO NOT EDIT.
# USE 'android update adb' TO GENERATE.
# 1 USB VENDOR ID PER LINE.
0x2a47

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-adb.rules
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2a47", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
ATTR{idVendor}=="2a47", ATTR{idProduct}=="201d", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="660", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1", TAG+="uaccess"
```

Is there anything I can do to have the device connected again - most importantly, so I can control it via `adb`?